# Определение выпуклости многоугольника

Tags: c++, математика

Всем доброго дня, есть задача определить выпуклость многоугольника. Пробовал через площади прямоугольников, достроенных от точек. Код выглядит приблизительно так.

```
bool convex(point *poligon_)
{
    double k = ((double)poligon_[3].y - poligon_[1].y) / (poligon_[3].x - poligon_[1].x);
    double a = poligon_[1].y - k*poligon_[1].x;
    double s1, s2;
    for (int i = poligon_[1].x; i <= poligon_[3].x; i += 0.001)
    {
        int y2 = k*i + a;
        s1 = (y2 - poligon_[3].y)*(i - poligon_[1].x);
        s2 = (poligon_[1].y - y2)*(poligon_[3].x - i);
        cout<< s1<<' '<< s2<<endl;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Разумеется не сработало, многоугольник задаю таким образом:

```
struct polygon {
    size_t size_polygon;
    point poligon_[];

    polygon()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            cout << "Пожалуйста введите количество вершин прямоугольника:" << endl;
            size_polygon = input_double(">>>");

            if (size_polygon < 3) continue;

            for (int i = 1; i < size_polygon +1; i++)
            {
                cout << "Координаты " << i << " точки"<<endl;
                poligon_[i].x = input_double("Введите координату x:" );
                poligon_[i].y = input_double("Введите координату y: ");
            }

            bool success = convex(poligon_);

            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Смотрел реализации других людей, данной проверки(на выпуклость), но выходило, либо слишком громоздко, либо не мог адаптировать под свои структуры. Жду конструктивной критики и попыток помочь.

Comment: Что тут думать-то? Обходите границу полигона, вектора-сегменты соседних отрезков должны все время поворачивать в одну сторону. Не забудьте проверить вектор, соединяющий последнюю точку с первой.

Comment: А чтобы проверить, в ту же сторону или нет, нужно проверить знаки псевдоскалярного произведения соседних сторон.

Comment: Ответы по вычисленю углов между векторами даны, только разберитесь, подходят ли под вашу задачу мнгогоугольники с пересечениями, например, такой пятиугольник как пятиконечная звезда.

Comment: Не понятно. Что значит обходить направо, налево? Если векторы это стороны многоугольника, то где начало и где считать конец вектора? Например, имеем квадрат(многоугольник) ABCD. Правильно ли я понимаю, что если обходим по часовой стрелке, то сначала делаем вычисления , например, для точки A, потом B, потом С, и, наконец ,D. Для точки А вектора будут AD и AB, соответственно. И координаты , для выражения Х1*У2-Х2*У1, будут, соответственно, не начала, а концы векторов: Х1,У1 это точка D, а Х2,У2, точка В? Практическое вычисление показало, что у двух соседних углов знак разный.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Многоугольник будет выпуклым если при его обходе в каждой тройке последовательных вершин происходит поворот всегда в одну и ту же сторону. При обходе многоугольника против часовой стрелке поворот будет всегда налево, а при обходе по часовой - направо.

Если одно ребро многоугольника соответствует вектору `AB`, а следующее за ним ребро соответствует вектору `BC`, то направление поворота в этой паре последовательных ребер будет задаваться знаком выражения

```
AB.x * BC.y - AB.y * BC.x
```

Для поворота налево это значение будет положительным, а для поворота направо - отрицательным (я предполагаю, что ось Y направлена вверх). Нулевое значение означает, что ребра коллинеарны.

Это дает нам алгоритм определения выпуклости. Для каждой вершины `i` нам надо вычислить

```
point ab = 
{ 
  poligon_[i].x - poligon_[i - 1].x, 
  poligon_[i].y - poligon_[i - 1].y
};

point bc = 
{ 
  poligon_[i + 1].x - poligon_[i].x, 
  poligon_[i + 1].y - poligon_[i].y
};

double product = ab.x * bc.y - ab.y * bc.x;
```

(Разумеется, надо быть аккуратным при вычислении индексов соседних точек `i - 1` и `i + 1` на краях массива)

По поведению знака величины `product` на всех вершинах многоугольника мы и получим ответ на наш вопрос о выпуклости.

Опять же, если заранее известно, что многоугольник обходится против часовой стрелки, то встретив первое отрицательное `product`, вы можете сразу говорить, что многоугольник невыпукл.

Если направление обхода заранее неизвестно, то придется проверить все вершины и убедиться, что знаки величины `product` везде одинаковы (и не забыть аккуратно обработать нулевое значение).

Answer (score 1):

Обходите границу полигона, вектора-сегменты соседних отрезков должны все время поворачивать в одну сторону.

Это означает, что у векторного произведения этих векторов координаты `z` должны быть одного знака.

Не забудьте проверить вектор, соединяющий последнюю точку с первой.

P.S.

> Пожалуйста введите количество вершин прямоугольника:

сюда я добавил бы список допустимых значений :).